# запуская tomcat 8,5 безрезультатно.всю работало вчера и неделю до того. ничего не менял

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

```
июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9713"]
июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9713"]
июн 07, 2017 6:14:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: поподробнее бы хотелось услышать о проблеме.

Comment: может какой из портов занят?

Comment: пытаюсь запустить наипростейший сервлет(который работал благополучно всю неделю) через eclipse, но север не стартует и выдает все указанное выше. если стартовать томкат вручную, то все работает и на нужный порт перехожу из браузера.

Comment: netstat -tldpn что выдаёт?

Comment: Никогда этой командой не пользовался, потому и не знаю что должно выдавать.Что смотреть?Как читать статистику?

Comment: если деплою war файл вручную, через админскую панель из браузера, то все опять же работает. какая то проблема в связке eclipse-tomcat